# How to pass jquery post result to another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery validate plugin to check available names.
It do post request to php file and get response 0 or 1.

The problem is that I cannot pass result to main function.
please see my code below

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("avaible", function(value, element) {

    $.post("/validate.php", { 
        friendly_url: value, 
        element:element.id 
    }, function(result) {  
        console.log(result)
    });

    //How to pass result here???
    console.log(result)  
}, "");
```

Comment: `myOtherFunction(result)`

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous javascript.

Comment: You're actually already doing it with `console.log(result)` as `console.log()` is a function. (I.e. to another function, but you can't return to the function that called the post to begin with)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as people already said, it is asynchronous and it is `myOtherFuntion` :-)

I just combine those comment into some kind of answer for you:

```
function myOtherFunction(result) {
// here you wrote whatever you want to do with the response result
//even if you want to alert or console.log
  alert(result);
  console.log(result);  
}

jQuery.validator.addMethod("avaible", function(value, element) {

    $.post("/validate.php", { 
        friendly_url: value, 
        element:element.id 
    }, function(result) {  
        myOtherFunction(result);
    });

    //How to pass result here???

    //there is no way to get result here 
    //when you are here result does not exist yet
}, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the asynchronous nature of Javascript, `console.log(result)` will not work because the server has not returned with the result data yet.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("avaible", function(value, element) {

$.post("/validate.php", { 
    friendly_url: value, 
    element:element.id 
}, function(result) {  
    console.log(result);
    doSomethingWithResult(result);
});

function doSomethingWithResult(result) {
    //do some stuff with the result here
}
}, "");
```

The above will allow you to pass the result to another function which will allow you to achieve accessing and working with the result once it has returned from the server.